# Using OBIEE Web Service (12c) to Determine Column Level Permissions

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am using the OBIEE web service to create a client that allows our internal users to check that our customers have access to various objects in OBIEE.

A use case might be - 'can user A read folder B?'.
This I've implemented just fine.

Another use case is 'can user A see characteristic B?'. Let's say characteristic B is the surname field on the employee table and in the RPD this has been limited to particular groups. One of our internal users has created a report for a customer and needs to verify that the customer will be able to see all of the columns in the analysis. We don't want to provide all of our internal users with 'Act As'.

The MetadataService's describeColumn doesn't provide me with permission info. I was hopeful that getSubItems might drill down far enough but it doesn't and neither does readObjects from the WebCatalogService.

Am I missing something or is this level of detail not available through the webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service won't do that for you, but there is a graph-analytics-based solution which does precisely what you want.

Comment: When you say 'graph-analytics-based solution' do you mean creating an analysis or something else?